# How to Write a Mockito+Junit test case for a method which reads the properties from properties file

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, junit4

I have to write a Mockito+Junit test for a method and that method reads the data from a properties file. When I am trying to execute my test case the properties file is loading but it is returning null. Following is my code:

```
 @RestController
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/example/prop.properties")
 public class ReadProp {
 @Value("${name}")
 private String name;
 @Value("${rollNo}")
 private String rollNo;
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public void getDetails(){
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(rollNo);
   }
 }
 The test case is as follows
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/example/prop.properties")
 public class ReadPropTest {
 @Mock
 private ReadProp readProp;
 @Value("${name}")
 private String name;
 @Value("${rollNo}")
 private String rollNo;
   @Test
   public void readValues() {
   System.out.println(name);
   System.out.println(rollNo);
   readProp.getDetails();

   }
 }
```

Comment: Your test runs via Mockito. Mockito does not know anything about Spring, so your `@PropertySource` annotation is ignored. The big question is, what do you want to test? The property reading part? In this case, you need to make the test a spring test. Or just the method, in which case you can use reflection to set the properties. And mocking the class your are testing is completely useless.

Comment: Here i just want to test the method and when i run the test case of that method it should load the actual class and should read the data from properties file and it should print the values..... if i am able to achieve this functionality i can solve problems in my project

Comment: i have removed the @Mock Annotation on ReadProp  class. and i ran the test case.. still it is not working with the above functionality.... if you can provide me a sample or reference that would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Let's start at the beginning... Your test has many problems, the first being that you don't actually have anything to test...

```
@Mock
private ReadProp readProp;
```

This, together with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` makes your `readProp` object a **mock** object. A mock object contains no logic. It has nothing to do with your original `ReadProp` class except the method names, etc. But the method themselves don't actually DO anything (unless you tell them to).

So, first problem: You are not test YOUR `RealProp` class, but a mock object, which doesn't help. You are creating something that only looks like a `RealProp` object and then you test that, but of course, that doesn't tell you anything. Mocks are there to help you simplify dependencies, etc. in your test - but it makes no sense to actually test the mock.

So, don't. Instead, make a real `RealProp`.

Another problem is, that System.out is not very good to test, but I assume that's just temporary code, so let's ignore that for a moment...

The next question is, what do you want to test. There are two possibilities:

a) You want to test that, under the assumption that the fields name and rollNo were filled correctly by whatever dependency injection framework (spring, in this case) you are using, the method `getDetails` will use them correctly.

b) You want to test that the injection of the values works and also the method `getDetails` uses that values.

These are two different tests. a) would be a true unit test, since it's limited to this "unit". b) would be more complex, since it doesn't just look at this unit, but also at the Spring environment around it. I would not go so far to call it an integration test, but it's more than a simple unit test.

Personally, I try to avoid the Spring environment in my unit tests as far as possible and concentrate on my own code, testing the Spring integration later in real integration tests, but that's as much personal preference as anything else.

Let's start with a)...

```
public class ReadPropTest {

      private ReadProp readProp = new ReadProp();

      @Before
      public void init() {
            Whitebox.setInternalState(readProp, "name", "someName");
            Whitebox.setInternalState(readProp, "rollNo", "someRollNo");
      }

      @Test
      public void myTest() {
      ...
      }
    }
```

Of course, you can also use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils instead of Mockito's Whitebox, doesn't matter.

And for b), you could try something like this. Of course you migth have to play around with the Configuration a bit, as it depends on your setup.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-spring.xml" })
public class ReadPropTest {
  @Autowired
  private ReadProp readProp;
  ...
}
```